# Loop for images not appearing correctly every second loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently using a function that is to loop through images.

On each image change the image should fade out, then animate a bounceinup for the next image.

If you look at my code, it currently works first time (and if you look at the commented out code, that works the SECOND time rather than the first) but then it stops fading out / animating the images and stacks them on top of each other.

```js
function loopImage() {
  //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
  var initialFadeIn = 1000;
  //interval between items (in milliseconds)
  var itemInterval = 6000;
  //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
  var fadeTime = 1000;
  //count number of items
  var numberOfItems = $('.explainerItem').length;
  //set current item
  var currentItem = 0;
  //show first item
  // $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);
  //loop through the items
  var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
    // $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);
    $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).toggleClass('bounceInUp');
    $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).addClass('fadeOut');

    if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
      currentItem = 0;
    } else {
      currentItem++;
    }
    $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).removeClass('fadeOut');
    $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).css('display', 'inline');
    $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).toggleClass('animated bounceInUp');
    // $('.explainerItem').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime,function () {
    /* $(this).toggleClass('animated bounceInUp')*/
    // });

    /*$('.explainerItem').removeClass('fadeOut');
    $('.explainerItem').css('display','none');*/
  }, itemInterval);
}
loopImage();

//$('.explainerItem').active(function(){*/
//  $('.explainerItem').addClass('animated bounceInUp');*/
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="explainer">
  <div class="explainerLink pull-center">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64/FF0000/FFFFFF.png&text=1" class="active animated bounceInUp" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64/00FF00/FFFFFF.png&text=2" class="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64/0000FF/FFFFFF.png&text=3" class="" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/64x64/FFFF00/FFFFFF.png&text=4" class="" />
  </div>

  <div class="explainerPlay pull-center">
    <h1>
      <a href="#videoModal">
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal"></i>
      </a>
    </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="explainerModal hide fade" id="videoModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="responsive-iFrame-explainer pull-center">
      <iframe width="0" height="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" class="video-vimeo team" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" src="videolink" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**added CSS**

```
.explainerItem {
    display: none;
    left: 30%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.explainerLink {
    height: 211px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your HTML markup has an `.explainerItem` class. By the way, you should really really cache it, because you make very repetitive DOM requests. Caching `$('.explainerItem')` (storing it once in a variable) would greatly improve performance.

Comment: After adding the correct class on `.explainerItem`s, here is what your code does : http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/GgVrgJ - not sure what it's actually supposed to do :) Besides, you didn't post any CSS so I improvised.

Comment: The explaineritem class exists in my html now. The second / first loop is still behaving differently. 

It either loops round once perfectly, or on the first or second loop it stacks the image / does not perform the animations in correct order (it'll fade in, disappear, reappear with the animation)

My commented out code works on the second loop (with the animations broken). The current code works fine on the first loop but on the second loop stacks up the images and doesn't fade them out.

Comment: Define "differently".

Comment: updated previous comment.

Comment: What do you think about the Pen I made from your code? Loops good, doesn't it?

Comment: Your pen works great, for some reason our code is still playing silly buggers and now not loading any image. I think I'll try make a gif and update it later to show how different it is behaving compared to the pen.